# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING, expecting ',' or ';' in /home/a6910668/public_html/event.php on line 83

Tags: php

I've looked at every other question involving this topic, but they are all in different situations, and I've tried to follow some of their tips to no avail. This is my code. The supposed error line is in bold.

```
echo " </select> :
<select name=\"event_time_mm\">
<option value=\"00\">00</option>
<option value=\"15\">15</options>
<option value=\"30\">30</options>
<option value=\"45\">45</options>
</select>
<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"m\" value=\"".$m"\">
**<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"d\" value=\"".$d"\">**
<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"y\" value=\"".$y"\">
<br/><br/>
<input type=\"submit\" name=\"submit\" value=\"Add Event\">
</form>";
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you are missing concatenation `.` with variables `$m`, `$d` ,`$y`

```
value=\"".$m."\">
```

add `.` after all these three variables.

Comment: Fixed it, thanks. I'm trying to teach myself and the book I have seems to have a lot of errors. The code above was copied straight from the book.

Comment: @mabwriter: My pleasure. Please accept the answer by clicking right arrow sign in the left

Answer (score 1):

Just to present another option, the heredoc syntax is quite nice for multi-line strings like this, e.g.:

```
echo <<<EOD
   <input type="hidden" name="m" value="$m">
   **<input type="hidden" name="d" value="$d">**
   <input type="hidden" name="y" value="$y">
EOD;
```

Answer (score 0):

Addendum: If you are already using double quotes, you should avoid the concatenation operator and switching in and out of the string altogether:

```
echo "
   <select>
   <input type=\"hidden\" name=\"m\" value=\"$m\">
   </form>";
```

Works the same.